# Concatenação HTML PHP

Tags: php, html

Abaixo segue o codigo e tem um comentário onde estou com problema na concatenação de html + php... erro bobo básico mas já fundi a cuca e não enxergo o problema. obrigado.

```
<?php
              // Monta consulta MySQL para o gráfico
              $sqlano = "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(dateent) as Year FROM `cadastro`";
              $queryano = $mysqli->query($sqlano);

?>

            <form method="GET" action="" name="menuForm">     
              <header>
                  <h3>Relatório de pedidos por mês do ano de: </h3>
                        <select id="ano" name="ano" onchange="document.forms['menuForm'].submit();">
                            <option value="2000" disabled selected> Escolha o ano </option> 

                                <?php
                                   while($dadosano = $queryano->fetch_array()){
                                   //essa linha abaixo estou com problema na concatenação mas já fundi a cabeça e não encontro o erro. 
                                   echo "<option value='".$dadosano['Year']."'  ". isset($_GET['ano']) && $_GET['ano']== $dadosano['Year']?' selected="selected"' : ' ' ;  "  > ".$dadosano['Year']. "</option>";

                                    }

                                 ?>

                          </select> 


              </header>
            </form>
```

Comment: E o que seria esse `;` no meio da linha, logo após a condição ternária?

Comment: é pra encerra a condição... condição ? codigoUm : codigoDois;

Comment: Não só está encerrando a condição como encerra o seu `echo`; tudo o que está depois dará erro de sintaxe (provavelmente o erro que obteve e omitiu na pergunta).

Comment: Não deu erro na execução porém a não fazia o que tem que fazer, popular o select e pegar o que fosse selecionado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é de sintaxe. Fazer:

```
echo "<option value='".$dadosano['Year']."'  ". isset($_GET['ano']) && $_GET['ano']== $dadosano['Year']?' selected="selected"' : ' ' ;  "  > ".$dadosano['Year']. "</option>";
```

Como você utilizou um `;` no meio da expressão, seria o mesmo que:

```
echo "<option value='".$dadosano['Year']."'  ". isset($_GET['ano']) && $_GET['ano']== $dadosano['Year']?' selected="selected"' : ' ';
"  > ".$dadosano['Year']. "</option>";
```

Essa segunda linha não é um PHP válido.

Fora isso, há muita responsabilidade para uma expressão apenas. Simplifique isso e não terá tantos problemas.

```
$selected = (isset($_GET['ano']) && $_GET['ano'] == $dadosano['Year']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
echo "<option value='{$dadosano['Year']}' {$selected}>{$dadosano['Year']}</option>";
```

Comment: Eu havia concatenado parte por parte e tbm não deu certo. Vou testar assim como informou... obrigado por enqto.

Comment: Agora deu certo... valeu

Comment: E como eu faço para resetar o select ao value=0 em caso de voltar a pagina ou reload na pagina pois apenas com o botão history.back ou reload não está zerando...voltando ao inicio

Comment: Ele só vai resetar quando não existir `$_GET['ano']`

Comment: Como faço para resetar a variavel  então quando fizer o reload ?  Tentei unset( $_GET['ANO'] ); porém devo estar fazendo algo errado.